# How do you break out of a loop by a terminating character?

Tags: c, for-loop, char

I am trying to write a simple demonstration program that will break out of a loop upon entering a designated character. I was able to do this successfully until I wanted to add the extra condition that I did not exceed my array. This code will not break out of the loop when I enter the designated character and I cannot figure out why. The logic and setup of the code seems sound!

```
#include <stdio.h>

char input[10];
char breakout = '!';
int idx;

int main(void)
{
printf("Input characters until %c character is used to break out", breakout);

for(idx = 0; input[idx] != breakout && idx < 10; idx++)
{
    scanf("%c", &input[idx]);
}

printf("Program terminated:");

getchar();
return 0;   
}
```

It seems as though the condition of the for loop SHOULD evaluate false upon entering the '!' character, but it is not. Thanks guys

Comment: Initialize `input` or you will access garbage value since first loop test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the condition before the character is entered, if you use a do-while loop you can make the comparison after

```
idx = 0;
do
{
    scanf("%c\n", &input[idx]);
}
while( input[idx++] != breakout && idx < 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Musa, however I tried to use the adjustment you suggested and it STILL is not breaking out of the loop when I use the breakout character. Might it be.. my compiler?

Comment: Great. That solved it. I'll change my best answer to whoever can answer this other dilemma I have with my code. My array is size 10. When I execute my code, it is only allowing me to input 5 inputs before the code terminates (half the size of the array). So I tried changing the array size to 20. I was then able to input 10 inputs (again half the size of the array). Why is this? I thought the 'pointer/array' arithmetic wouldn't allow this.

Comment: @SmithWillSuffice do you increment `idx` in more than one place?

Comment: No Musa, I swear, the code that I posted is what I used. And when I implemented the suggestions you all provided I did it verbatim. But whenever I run the code, after I input 5 characters, it breaks out of the loop and terminates the program. Have you tried running it?

Comment: It just does not make sense. I mean, if you make an array with 10 elements, it should allow 10 inputs I imagined, not half of that. But that is what is happening when I run it.

Comment: @SmithWillSuffice how do you know it only allows 5 inputs?

Comment: When I ran the program. I was testing the code, and I tried running it to test that the loop would exit if I input 10 characters (NOT the break character). I enter a character. Hit enter. Enter another character. Hit enter. I do this 5 times, and then the program exits the loop and goes to my print statement.

Comment: I had to run the program to discover this bug.

Comment: @SmithWillSuffice you're picking up the enter character also, see updated answer

Comment: That's what I thought! But I was under the impression that the return character was not being stored! I am such a novice! So for this code I will have to DOUBLE the size of my array to allow for the return character. You helped me enormously, and I greatly appreciate your time and depth of explanation and for spending your time in helping a noob programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Think about your for loop conditions. Your `input[idx]` is always looking at the next location in the array (which does not yet contain a character)--not the previous character received from the scanf call, which would be found at `input[idx - 1]`. But of course you can't check `input[idx - 1]` on the first iteration, so watch out for that.

```
for(idx = 0; (idx == 0 || input[idx - 1] != breakout) && idx < 10; idx++) 
{    
  ... 
}
```

Super-complex for loop conditions are rarely a good idea for more or less this reason--that `idx++` iteration step occurs before the evaluation of the condition and it can be confusing. Use a do/while or have a break condition in your loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I needed that further explanation, as I apparently had a flaw in my understanding of how the for loop conditions were evaluated. I thought that the check would have checked input[idx] and NOT input[idx -1].

Answer (score 1):

You should testing the condition after the character is inputted. I modified your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char input[10];
char breakout = '!';
int idx;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Input characters until %c character is used to break out", breakout);

    for(idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
    {
            scanf("%c", &input[idx]);
            if(input[idx] == '!')
              break;
    }
    printf("Program terminated:");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However the code is only allowing me to input 5 characters, not 10 before terminating?  The array is set to 10, so it doesn't make sense why only 5 inputs are allowed? I am stumped in earnest.

Comment: This problem is that is buffer is not cleared.You can add below code before scanf(getchar) sentence: If your OS is Linux :__fpurge(stdin); It will clear buffer.Note:There are two '_' before fpurge. You should include <stdio_ext.h>;If your OS is windows : fflush(stdin);